# meaning of out in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **out** in the following sentence?

> Thus, along with the global inequity in accessing vaccination, India is seeing a version of it play out three months since vaccinations began.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"out" here is part of the phrasal verb "play out".

'Play out' means happen or take place.

So the sentence can be rewritten as "India is seeing a version of it take place three months since vaccinations began."